# Where is $f(z)=Im(z^2)$ differntiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Where is $f(z)=Im(z^2)$ differntiable?

So what I tried $f(z)=f(x+iy)=Im((x+iy)^2)=2x^2y^2$

Then by Cauchy Riemann: $U_x=V_y \rightarrow 8y^2x=0$ and $U_y=-V_x \rightarrow 8x^2y=0$. Then, my conclusion is that $f$ is differentiable on points $(0,a)$ and $(a,0)$ with $a \in \mathbb R$. However, the solution states the function is only differentiable at $(0,0)$.

But for instance if I set at the first equation $x=0$, then $y$ is arbitrary, and same if I set $y=0$. So what is correct here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for $\operatorname{Im}((x+iy)^2)$ is incorrect:
$$ (x+iy)^2 = x^2-y^2+2xyi, $$
so the imaginary part is $2xy$. Now apply the Cauchy–Riemann equations, and you should get $2x=0=2y$.